# Angular 9 - Pending request forever

Tags: angular, .net-core

I just upgrade my project from angular 8 to 9 and using dotnet core 3.1 as my backend. 
I tested today click on the link to request http get and sometimes I got (pending). It stays pending and not done. I check the backend, it has no error. I attached the picture to show you, all the links are the same with just different parameter like id

[image]

Comment: Same problem. Sometimes request remains in pending until I reboot server